# Easy PHP erro ao iniciar, Could not load the file"run-devserver.bmp Easy php

Tags: php, easyphp

Utilizo o Windows XP por questões de meu computador ser do ano de 2011 e no Windows 7  ele trava demais, quando tento abrir o `Easy PHP` da um erro que é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia ajudar? (Não posso trocar de OS)

Comment: Por curiosidade, qual versão do easyphp estava usando e qual pasta estava instalado?

Answer (score 2):

A solução que encontrei foi:

- Baixar o [Ampps](https://www.ampps.com/). Ele também está disponível para o *Windows XP*;